# Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to refer to a cell value in another ***closed*** workbook with a formula (not VBA!). The **Sheet name is stored as a variable** (in the following example, C13 is "Sheet2").

If the other file is open, then following works:

```
=INDIRECT("[myExcelFile.xlsm]" & C13 & "!$A$1")
```

If the file is closed, the above formula doesn't work, as there is no absolute path given. But I got it work with following (give attention to ' instead of ":

```
='C:\data\[myExcelFile.xlsm]Sheet2'!$A$1
```

Now I want to replace the hardcoded "Sheet2" with a **dynamic referenced** value, means with C13 (as seen in the first code snippet).

Does anybody know a solution without using VBA or other libraries?

Answer (score 14):

There is definitively [no way to do this](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1683-excel-convert-text-string-to-formula.html) with standard formulas.  However, a crazy sort of answer can be found [here](http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function).  It still avoids VBA, and it will allow you to get your result dynamically.

1. First, make the formula that will generate your formula, but don't add the `=` at the beginning!
2. Let us pretend that you have created this formula in cell `B2` of `Sheet1`, and you would like the formula to be evaluated in column `c`.
3. Now, go to the Formulas tab, and choose "Define Name".  Give it the name `myResult` (or whatever you choose), and under Refers To, write `=evaluate(Sheet1!$B2)`  (note the `$`)
4. Finally, go to `C2`, and write `=myResult`.  Drag down, and... *voila!*

Comment: Thanks for this answer, +1. 
But as you already added to your answer: this only gives me one dynamically created formula. But I want to duplicate the whole sheet and apply the formula to these - without create couples of name defines. 
Why are you sure (by design), that there is definitively no other way?

Comment: I made a citation for why I was so definitive that there is no other way (short of VBA), and I removed "by design" (because I wasn't involved with the design of Excel - "evaluate text as a regular function" just doesn't seem in the spirit of Excel.  I probably overstated my case).  Also, I found a better citation for the answer, which led to a more useful, draggable function.  Hopefully this meets your needs better!

Comment: I don't know why (and I didn't add the "="), but unfortunately above solution (evaluate function in name definition) did not work for my problem (#REF error). With other examples it worked (simple 1+2 operations etc.) - also with your second tip by dragging down worked - but not for the closed workbook.

Comment: Oh - then I've got nothing.  No VBA is really a constraint?

Comment: Ok, nevertheless thanks! Regarding VBA... For this question, I don't want to use VBA... ;)

Comment: @Chris Very old question, but for completeness (as this question pops up quite high in the search results) herewith a workaround solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53477902/9211191

Comment: does not work for me either with INDIRECT formulas to closed workbook string references

Comment: Please add an example using INDIRECT on a closed workbook. The "crazy sort of answer" is nice to know but does not help when using INDIRECT on closed workbooks

Comment: @Porsche911 I would if I had one.  They've made a lot of updates in the intervening years since I wrote this answer, including putting Office on the cloud.  Perhaps cloud-based documents are considered always open?  I don't have any answers for you.

Answer (score 5):

I too was looking for the answer to referencing cells in a closed workbook. Here is the link to the solution (correct formula) below. I have tried it on my current project (referencing a single cell and an array of cells) and it works well with no errors. I hope it helps you.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4226-excel-reference-unopened-file.html

In the formula, `E:\Excel file\` is the full file path of the unopened workbook, `test.xlsx` is the name of the workbook, `Sheet2` is the sheet name which contains the cell value you need to reference from, and `A:A,2,1` means the cell `A2` will be referenced in the closed workbook. You can change them based on your needs.

If you want to manually select a worksheet to reference, please use this formula

`=INDEX('E:\Excel file\[test.xlsx]sheetname'!A:A,2,1)`

After applying this formula, you will get a Select Sheet dialog box, please select a worksheet and then click the OK button. Then the certain cell value of this worksheet will be referenced immediately.

Comment: Does it also work with variable sheet name, which is one of the core question?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that a link to a closed file works with index( but not with index(indirect(

It seems to me that it is a programming issue of the index function.
I solved it with a if clause row

```
C2=sheetname
if(c2=Sheet1,index(sheet1....),if(C2="Sheet2",index(sheet2....
```

I did it over five sheets, it's a long formula, but does what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Check INDEX Function:

```
=INDEX('C:\path\[file.xlsm]Sheet1'!A10:B20;1;1)
```

Comment: This works if the workbook ``file.xlsm`` is closed. However, it does not work if we want to make the sheet name a variable, like this: `"'C:\path\[file.xlsm]" & A1 & "'!A10:B20"`.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the great question. I want to clarify and second the solution posted by Philipp. The solution does the following:

1. Updates data from a **closed** Excel file, and
2. Does so **"dynamically"** (though not exactly - you'll see)

In his answer above, Philipp said: "The problem is that a link to a closed file works with index( but not with index(indirect("

I believe this is still true. (I'm using Office 365 here in March of 2021. It would be so nice if Microsoft allowed INDIRECT and INDEX to play nicely together with closed files!)

I can confirm that Philipp's workaround indeed works, practically speaking. From the user's point of view, it feels like what Chris, the OP, wants to do.

Let's say you want the contents of a given cell to be drawn from Sheet1, Sheet2 or Sheet3, which are from a closed file myExcelFile.xlsm. You will choose which sheet by changing the contents of a particular cell (C13, as in the OP Chris's question). One way to do this is to make it a drop-down list (using Data > Data Validation > Allow [List]). The list will have the following names:

Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3

(This will generalize without the drop-down list. For example, you can just type "Sheet2" into C13, and the relevant data from the closed file will appear; if you then type "Sheet3" then the data from *that* sheet will appear instead. Or you can have a column with the sheet names, and the next column over [with the formula below, adjusted] for the output from the closed file.)

The cell that will contain the referenced data from the other, closed sheet (myExcelFile.xlsm) will have:

```
=IFS(
C13="Sheet1",'C:\data\[myExcelFile.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1,
C13="Sheet2",'C:\data\[myExcelFile.xlsm]Sheet2'!$A$1,
C13="Sheet3",'C:\data\[myExcelFile.xlsm]Sheet3'!$A$1
)
```

And that's it.

It'll throw up a #REF error the first time you do this with myExcelFile.xlsm closed, but you can go to Data > Queries & Connections > Edit Links > Update Values and your values from the closed file should appear. (Personally, I set up a macro with a button to do the updating, instead of hunting through the menus.) The magic is that when you do Update Values, the data from all of the sheets in the closed file get loaded into the current Excel file - so you don't have to update every time you switch the reference to a different sheet (Sheet2 to Sheet3, for example).

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run *any macro* for this.

Place this Function inside any Module (i.e. Modules>Module1):

```
Function EXTINDIRECT(sFolder As String, sFile As String, sSheet As String, sRef As String) As Variant
' Returns a value with INDIRECT from a Closed File
    EXTINDIRECT = GetObject(sFolder & sFile).Worksheets(sSheet).Range(sRef)
End Function
```

And, for as any Function, this works inside any cell as:

```
=EXTINDIRECT("c:\my\path";"MyFile.xlsx";"MySheet1";"$A$1")
```

Don't abuse from it, since `GetObject` is actually opening a file in the background every time you use it.
At the end, choose to NOT save the file, since if you choose to save it, the process hides it.

Tested in MS Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

=INDIRECT("'C:\Data["&A8&"]SheetNAME'!$G9")

where A8 contains myExcelFile.xlsm

and G9 contains your source workbook precious data.

Comment: The question regards to a variable sheet name, means to make "SheetNAME" flexible in your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of sheet you want to reference you can use below function to find out the name. Than you can use it in INDIRECT funcion.

```
Public Function GETSHEETNAME(address As String, Optional SheetNumber As Integer = 1) As String

    Set WS = GetObject(address).Worksheets
    GETSHEETNAME = WS(SheetNumber).Name

End Function
```

This solution doesn't require referenced workbook to be open - Excel gonna open it by itself (but it's gonna be hidden).

Comment: Dear Stefan, what is the "address" in your VBA example? Is it the filepath?

Comment: Yes, it's a full file path e.g. C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\file.xlsx. Usually I do input the file path in the cell for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Here's a dinosaur method for you on Office 2010.

Write the full address you want using concatenate (the "&" method of combining text).

Do this for all the addresses you need. It should look like:

="="&"'\FULL NETWORK ADDRESS including [Spreadsheet Name]"&W3&"'!$w4"

The W3 is a dynamic reference to what sheet I am using, the W4 is the cell I want to get from the sheet.

Once you have this, start up a macro recording session. Copy the cell and paste it into another. I pasted it into a merged cell and it gave me the classic "Same size" error. But one thing it did was paste the resulting text from my concatenate (including that extra "=").

Copy over however many you did this for. Then, go into each pasted cell, select he text and just hit enter. It updates it to an active direct reference.

Once you have finished, put the cursor somewhere nice and stop the macro. Assign it to a button and you are done.

It is a bit of a PITA to do this the first time, but once you have done it, you have just made the square peg fit that daamned round hole.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2016 at least, you can use INDIRECT with a full path reference; the entire reference (including sheet name) needs to be enclosed by `'` characters.

So this should work for you:

```
= INDIRECT("'C:\data\[myExcelFile.xlsm]" & C13 & "'!$A$1")
```

Note the closing `'` in the last string (ie `'!$A$1` surrounded by `""`)

Comment: Unfortunately same behavior: it only works with opened source workbook. The specialty of the question is to create reference to another closed (!) workbook.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work with closed file: add a pivot table (rows, tabular layout, no subtotals, no grand totals) of the source to the current workbook, then reference all you want from that pivot table, INDIRECT, LOOKUPs,...

Answer (score -1):

I was disappointed so I made the following workaround:

1. I created my INDIRECT commands and stored them just outside the desired range. Of course I get errors when the source workbook is closed but they light up when it's open.
2. So I open the source workbook temporarily.
3. Then I created a macro that copies the INDIRECT formulas from outside the range and pastes them inside the range. All cells are filled in with the right values.
4. The macro then copy-pastes the values of the range to the range on top of themselves. This deletes the formulas but keeps their values.
5. Then I close the source workbook. My values stay intact where I want them and my INDIRECT formulas stay just outside the desired range in case I want to refresh them by repeating the procedure!

This workaround saves me the error of the indirect formulas when the source workbook is closed, and most importantly it saves a lot of time in recalculations!

Hope this works for you too!