# Reading from a series of Excel Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say that I would like to read something from one Excel workbook, into another. This could be done typing

```
='C:\Documents\[MyOtherExcelFile]Sheet1'!A1
```

But suppose that I dont have a single file, but rather 100 (or 1.000) other Excel Workbooks, each from which I need a few values.

Assuming that they are named systematically like this:

```
C:\Doecuments\ExcelSeriesFile_0001.xlsx
C:\Doecuments\ExcelSeriesFile_0002.xlsx
C:\Doecuments\ExcelSeriesFile_0003.xlsx 
(...)
C:\Doecuments\ExcelSeriesFile_1000.xlsx
```

Is there any way that I can automaticcaly create the name of the file, in the read command, getting the four digit number from a cell value in my original sheet?

Preferably I would like to do this without VBA, but if this is needed (or if it simply makes it easier/more effective) then VBA is okay.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the INDIRECT function for this.... give me a minute and I'll write up an answer for you.

Comment: Come to think of it INDIRECT will need the other workbook to be open to work..... so probably won't be what you're after.

Comment: The idea wasn't half bad, I actually did manage to get something working using INDIRECT. However I think you are correct in saying that the file needs to be either open or added as a connection, which is kind of problematic. I wonder if there is a workaround for this...?

Comment: Have added in comments as it's not the answer you're looking for:  
**=INDIRECT("[ExcelSeriesFile_" & TEXT(A2,"0000") & ".xlsx]Sheet3!$A$1")** - where cell A2 holds the file number.  But the file has to be open.

Comment: Unfortunately, no real good answer here without VBA / Add-ins - Here's a link to another time this question was asked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28461672/1693085

Comment: Fair enough, I will have to look into a solution using VBA then. I will try to remember to post it here, if I find a good solution. Thanks for the answers...