# Cannot reference to another spreadsheet using SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the last value of every S/N. Which means to say if I reference to '1a', I should get '23'.

I tried using **`=INDEX(B1:B9,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A2:A9=E7)*ROW(A2:A9))))`** for the following, which works for the same spreadsheet, however I cannot reference S/N and Value in other spreadsheets. I get a **`#REF!`**.

```
S/N Value
1a  41
2a  41
3a  23
4a  342
1a  31
1a  23
3a  43
2a  54
```

Is there another formula to reference to other spreadsheet?

Comment: Do you mean in another _sheet_ or another _workbook_ ? If it's another workbook - is the workbook open or closed?

Comment: I meant another work book.  The work book is closed

Comment: See my edited answer with @Macro Man pointing out my failure to read the question properly :-) If you had it open to start with, then Excel would take care of the fullpath addition for you...

Comment: @MacroMarc in your defence, the question doesn't actually state that the other workbook is closed :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the other spreadsheet like:

EDIT: When other workbook is closed, this needs to be entered with the full path.

```
 'C:\Property Audits\Western Region\Apartments\[Other Workbook.xlsx]Name of Sheet in Other Workbook'!B1:B9
```

Do this wherever there is a range of cells that you are referencing in the other workbook.

Comment: If the workbook is closed it needs the full path, not just the workbook name [see this question for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28461672/4240221)