# Excel externally linked data formula turns to #REF upon opening workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

A very similar question was asked [3 years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/629514/excel-linked-data-formula-turns-to-ref-upon-opening-workbook) but with no satisfactory answer.

I have the following folder structure

```
|--A
|----A.xlxs
|--B
|----B.xlxs
```

`A.xlsx` looks like so
[image]

`B.xlsx` Looks like so
[image]

And when I apply the below (untested) function to column 2 of spreadsheet `A.xlsx`, it looks exactly like spreadsheet `B.xlsx`

```
INDEX(C:\....\B\[B.xlxs]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$5,MATCH(A2,C:\....\B\[B.xlxs]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$5))
```

[image]

And now every time I open `B.xlsx`, **without changing a single thing**, I get this result in `A.xlsx`

**Questions:**

- Why does this happen?
- How can I prevent this from happening?
- How can I use relative, instead of global, paths (ie. ensure it works if I transfer to a USB drive)?

**Additional Info:**

- My files are stored on a NAS, if that makes a difference

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Get and Transform (Power Query)? I can't remember if it supports relative pathing natively yet, but there are ways to trick it into doing so. The only caveat with Power Query is I believe you can't update the data from "B.xlsx" if "B.xlsx" is open. In any case, from what I remember, setting up relative paths for external references in formulas using Indirect has issues.

Comment: @Wedge I don't know what Get/Transform/Power Query are. But it seems to me either I am doing something very wrong, my operating system is changing file names, or Excel 2016 has a serious design issue.

Comment: I don't think so you can do it with closed workbook. See [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28461672/1652222) similar question.