# Index() & Indirect() on a closed Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a few closed Excel workbooks, which I would be willing to access with `=INDEX(MATCH)` without openning them.

Unfortunately, I want to refer to them indirectly, thus based on the current sheet I am in.

E.g. - if I am in `sheet` -> `then file path`:

`AAB` -> `'C:\Users\vityata\Desktop\[AAB]Test'!$A:E`

`BBC` -> `'C:\Users\vityata\Desktop\[BBC]Test'!$A:E`

It seems like a trivial task, but the only options to do something like this seem to be the following:

- Open the sheet and then use `Indirect()` (but I do not want to open the sheet)
- Use VBA code (but it should be somehow reusable and really last resort)
- Use data connection (I do not want it)
- Use `INDIRECT.EXT` (but I do not want 3. party add-ins)

I have checked similar problems here: [How to referencing value in closed excel workbook by formula incl. variable sheetname?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/how-to-referencing-value-in-closed-excel-workbook-by-formula-incl-variable-shee) but the first solution is rather too colmplicated to do it.

Any new ideas or best practices?

**Update**
So far I have achieved the following with VBA (although I would love to have a non-VBA solution):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub VlookupClosedWb(Optional strLookFor As String = "Erteilung Baugenehmigung", _
                        Optional strSheet As String = "APF", _
                        Optional lngColIndex As Long = 2)

    Dim strRange As String

    strRange = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\[" & strSheet & ".xlsx]" & "Monatsbericht'!$A:$E"
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & strLookFor & """," & strRange & "," & lngColIndex & ",0)"

End Sub

Public Function fVlookupClosedWb(Optional strLookFor As String = "Erteilung Baugenehmigung", _
                        Optional strSheet As String = "APF", _
                        Optional lngColIndex As Long = 2)

    Dim strRange    As String

    strRange = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\[" & strSheet & ".xlsx]" & "Monatsbericht'!$A:$E"

    fVlookupClosedWb = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(""" & strLookFor & """, " & strRange & ", " & lngColIndex & ", 0)

End Function
```

Long story short - the Sub works as expected, providing exactly what I want in the active cell. The Function does not work. Any ideas how to make it work? I suppose that it does not work, because I am abusing a bit `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, but I cannot pass a range without openning the other workbook. Ideas?

Comment: Maybe try showing your code based on the linked question so others can see what you did and might be able to spot where you went wrong.

Comment: @FreeMan - Just done it. I did not want to work with `VBA` and it was actually my last resort...

Comment: Also, did you try the "crazy sort of method" linked in [Choirbean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463798/2344413)'s answer? Looks like that might just work for you.

Comment: @FreeMan - tried it, but it is too complicated. I would rather start openning the files and resolve the problem with `Indirect` than doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I found out that the way to use some formulas on a closed excel workbook, without referring to the path is by using the [`Sumproduct()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).

---

E.g.:
If you want to use Sumproduct() as an alternative of Sumifs() this is how it looks like with two conditions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B6=C2)*1)*(A2:A6=D2))
*SUMPRODUCT(((B8:B13=C8)*1)*(A8:A13=D8))
*SUMPRODUCT(((B16:B20=C16)*1)*(A16:A20=D16))
```

I have put [some more examples of it here](http://www.vitoshacademy.com/excel-use-sumproduct-instead-of-sumifs-or-countifs/).