# Changing a file location for 10,000+ cells in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, variables, repeat

I'm creating a workbook in Excel, and need it to reference other workbooks. I am pulling information from about 30 cells for each day of the year. Each day of the year is a separate workbook. So, I have over 10,000 cells that I need to change if I just copy and paste the formulas for each day.

The reference I have right now is something like this:

`='C:\user\data\year\[day.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1)`

Where that A1 will be replaced by 30 other cells, and the day.xlsx will be replaced with all of the days in a year. For everything I've tried so far Excel has asked me to manually locate each file per cell.

Is there any way to make this process quicker than manually changing the file name for every single one of these cells? Maybe be able to set the date in the file name to a variable that will link to a cell?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's most likely due to wrong format of your reference. You have to add `\ ` after the path and before the `[filename]`

Comment: That's just how stack overflow formatted it, I didn't notice it when I posted so added a space so the \ would show up. It is in the correct format on my workbook. However, that's not what I was asking about.

Comment: What is the layout of your consolidated workbook? For example, is it a different row for each day of the year? or is it a different worksheet? what is the range of cells you copy from each worksheet? I suggest you add these details.

Comment: How often do the "day" workbooks change?  I.e. are they just created and, after that, never changed again, or do people go in and change the contents on later dates?  (A workbook that is linked to 365 other, un-opened, workbooks is potentially going to be sloooooow to use so, if the data you are retrieving is static, it would probably be better to put the values into your workbook rather than constantly linking to the information in other workbooks.)

Answer (score 1):

To summarize: You want to create addresses in the stated format by string manipulation and then query their value.

There is in fact a function for this, it is called `INDIRECT`. Unfortunately it requires the source file to be open for external references, so I'm not sure if it is any help to you. I have never tried to open 365 excel files at once. 
See also [this question on that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect).

If you do not wish to open all the files by hand you will probably have to fall back on VBA (or perhaps JavaScript if you use Office 2016). It shouldn't be to difficult to create a macro which generates the references for you.

Here is a starting point for such a macro:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Dim day As Integer

    For day = 1 To 365
        Cells(day, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "='[BASENAME" & day & ".xlsx]SHEETNAME'!R1C1"
    Next i
End Sub
```

One more thing: After that your workbook will be linked to all those day-files. As such it will reflect changes as they occur in the day-files. If that is not required it would probably be best to sever the connections and replace each reference with its value. You can do that via `Data->Queries&Connections->Manage Links->sever connection` (I'm translating from my localized excel version so the exact names may vary) OR you can just copy every thing and then paste only values.