# Concatenate seem to wrap in quotes prior to indirect

Tags: excel-formula, excel-indirect

Goal: Pull data from another excel sheet but name of excel sheet is changed yearly

Thoughts: Excel seems to wrap the below in double quotes. While this may be the problem it is unclear how to resolve it.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(B2,"FY",RIGHT(Financal_Year,2),"_Attendance","\","[FY",RIGHT(Financal_Year,2)," LOG.xlsx]JUN'!B19)"))
```

In "Show Calculation Steps" I can see that the evaluation looks correct with the EXPECTATION of the double quotes placed where concatenate place its data.

Example Output:

```
=INDIRECT("'\\networkdrive\FY18_Attendance\[FY18_LOG.xlsx]JUN'!B19")
```

The output I'm looking for:

```
=INDIRECT('\\netwrokdrive\FY18_Attendance\[FY18 LOG.xlsx]JUN'!B19)
```

This way it grabs the data in that block.

Comment: `INDIRECT` can not reference to external workbook with network drive path concatenation at least up to Excel 2007.  But if you can trim the external path down to `=CONCATENATE("'[FY",RIGHT(Financal_Year,2)," LOG.xlsx]JUN'!B19")` with that spreadsheet opened, you may get your result.  Otherwise, try the `EVALUATE` function from this post (assuming you have a newer version of Excel): See this post for some details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would create a shortcut to the current year file and then link my references through that shortcut. Then every year you only have to update what the "current fy" link points to and all other refs fall in line.

I.e. if you want fy18's cell b19 you would insert the following into a cell.

='\\server\path\[current-fy-shortcut.lnk]sheet1'!b19

And then change the current-fy-shortcut to point to fy18-blahblah.xlsx

There may be a way to build the fy reference with indirect but it seems like a whole lot of work for worse payoff. You have to open the referenced workbook for indirect to "see" it(every time). with the method above you just have to change a pointer once a year.

Hope this helps,
SySfS