# Excel VBA: Getting cell value from unopened .xlsx file

Tags: vba, excel

So basically I want to write Macros that automatically (in other document) counts range value based on other cell value and then exports it to the template excel file.

I have this code that gets the path to the file from which the data should be extracted:

```
Sub GetFilePath()
Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim BBuy, SSell As String

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With myFile
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Fileselected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
```

Then value of Fileselected = "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\report sample.xlsx"

How can I then reference this Excel file in an =SUMIF formula?

I tried something like as below but didn't really work, and also Google did not really help:

```
BBuy = "Buy"
Fileselected.Formula = "=sumif(A2:A2500, BBuy, N2:N2500)"
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a bit tough, but here you may see options  - 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the formula easier to read, I declared the SumIf criteria's and a variable X which is where the output of SumIf will be stored.

```
Dim MyRange1 as Range
MyRange1 = myFile.Sheets("Your Sheet Name Here").Range("A2:A2500")
Dim MyRange2 as Range
MyRange2 = myFile.Sheets("Your Sheet Name Here").Range("N2:N2500")
Dim BBuy as String
BBuy = "Buy"

Dim X as Variant
X = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf((MyRange1, BBuy, MyRange2)
```

You dont have to declare these as variables as you can just reference them in the formula and reduce the above code down to one line (2 lines including "Dim X as Variant"). For instance, to replace your ranges and criteria in the formula:

```
X = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(myFile.sheets("Your Sheet Name Here").Range("A2:A2500), "Buy", myFile.Sheets("Your Sheet Name Here").Range("N2:N2500))
```

Now you have the answer you want stored in the variable "X". You can just set a range on your current workbook to equal X if you just want to value pasted somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Heyho,

if you want to refer on a range or cell of another sheet you have to try it like the following:

```
'path[filename.xls]Sheetname'!$A$2:$A$2500
```

Did you try to use that already?