# Excel Indirect function to external workbook - REF! result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was writing a function to link indirectly to an external workbook and I came up with this:

```
=+INDIRECT("=+'"&$W$2&"\"&$Y$4&"\"&$X$4&"\["&$W$4&"]"&MID($W$4,1,LEN($W$4)-4)&"'!"&$U$15)
```

That though returns `#REF!` as result

The part within the () brackets, when evaluated return the following:
  `"=+'C:\Folder0\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\
[MyFile.csv]NameTab'!$D$2"`

and if I were to use it directly in a cell (once evaluated) would work

Could someone help me understand what is wrong here?

Comment: `INDIRECT` function is designed to work with open workbooks only.

Comment: What would be an equivalent that works on closed workbooks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above, Indirect() referencing external workbooks only works when the external workbook is open, which defeats the purpose.

The morefunc.xll (google it) add-in has a function called Indirect.ext, which works with closed external workbooks, but there are some limitations (i.e. it does not work in newer versions of Excel).

This post in [XtremeVBTalk](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/excel/312473-indirectex-indirect-closed-workbooks.html) claims it has a better approach.