# Use the value in a cell as part of the workbook name for a reference to an external closed workbook

Tags: excel, external

Apologies if this sounds familiar. I have read through lots of answers to similar sounding problems but I don't think they fix my issue. I am a novice Excel user, and I'm making these spreadsheets in a volunteer capacity so I already slightly resent the time I've spent on this!!
We want to have a separate, distinct excel workbook for every day of the year, so people logging visitor numbers can fill in just that simple sheet. With, for eg, a cell for "adult visitors", "child visitors" etc (there are many types of visitor, it turns out)
I can call these workbooks whatever I want so I'm going to say "EODdaily" followed by the date, eg "EODdaily20220601".
Management want their own workbook, with a row for each day of the month, taking the figures from the daily workbooks. I can generate the name of the daily workbook in my summary workbook and that can be dragged down but is it possible to use this name to pull the correct data in?

So for my 1/6/2022 row I have in cell BU4 the filename I want to get the data from, with the correct path - if I copy and paste (value not formula) this into another cell it returns the number I want. But I can't work out how to get the value of the thing pointed to by cell BU4.
[the path I've generated to point to the file, sitting in cell BU4, works when I copy and paste it in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4XKD.png)

I hope this makes sense. It feels like I'm very close, but is it even possible without learning macros?? OH and of course the daily workbook will be closed when management are looking at theirs.
Another complication: even if I can do this for the first row I want to be able to drag it down, I don't think it's going to be possible is it...

Comment: You may want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621636/excel-indirect-function-to-external-workbook-ref-result

Comment: Thanks anonymous but doesn't INDIRECT only work on open workbooks? These workbooks are used by two different teams of people.

Comment: Yes. That is what it is stated there. But also some “work-arounds” given.

Comment: "morefunc" is someone else's VBA presumably?? That is (anecdotally, have not yet even worked out how to use it) not supported on later versions of Excel, the other link unfortunately seems to have disappeared.