# Excel - External link to multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any help would be much appreciated.

My aim is to pull specific cell data from multiple excel workbooks into a master excel spreadsheet.
For example I want to pull the contents of cell B2 from many other workbooks to create a list so there would be a row for each workbook.
I want these external links to remain as the contents of B2 may change over time.

I know how to do this manually by changing the formula to match the file name, however is there a more efficient way to amend the formula to match a workbook name I've manually input under a column?

I hope this makes sense,

Kind regards,

Thomas

Comment: Try the [INDIRECT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function. But this won't automatically update the data from other workbooks until they are being opened simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Dattel is correct in suggesting `INDIRECT` and also has pointed out that `INDIRECT` is meant for workbooks that are open. If this is no issue to you then the following formula would get you started.

```
=INDIRECT("'["&A1&".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1")
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Book1 | =INDIRECT("'["&A1&".xlsx]Sheet1'!A1") |

This would obtain the book name as a reference from cell `A1` and get you the same results as manually entering the name (Cell A1 of Book1.xlsx Sheet1).

Take a look at this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621636/excel-indirect-function-to-external-workbook-ref-result).