# How to reference files, each in a different folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 100 Excel files, and each file is located on diffrent folder in the drive.

For eg.

```
file 1 = C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\2018_11_26.0001\Excel.xlsx  
file 2 = C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\2018_11_26.0002\Excel.xlsx 
file 3 = C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\2018_11_26.0003\Excel.xlsx
.
.
.
file 100 = C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\2018_11_26.0100\Excel.xlsx
```

In each Excel file, the data is located at `cell (1,1)`.

I want to take the data from every Excel file and save it in one Excel file in one column.

The code I have, was good enough for small amount of data,

```
a=xlsread('K:\Repeatability\C1X\2018-11-07.0001\Radial_Accuracy.xlsx'); 

b=xlsread('K:\Repeatability\C1X\2018-11-07.0002\Radial_Accuracy.xlsx'); 

N=[a(1:1,:) ; b(1:1,:)] 
xlswrite('K:\Repeatability_Test\New.xlsx',N);
```

In this case and in future, I'll have a bigger amount of data. I don't want to specify each folder location.

Comment: you may use excel vba to draw these data and output into one excel file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: @KetanSahu As I said in my comment, please [edit] your question and add that code that you already have. We can only help to improve that code if we can see what you already did.

Comment: Hey @Pᴇʜ,

As, I said in my question, I have a code which I was using for small amount of data. However, I got stuck with the bigger amount of data. And I wasn't getting how to do that.

The code I was using before for my small amout of data id here. 

a=xlsread('K:\Repeatability\C1X\2018-11-07.0001\Radial_Accuracy.xlsx');
b=xlsread('K:\Repeatability\C1X\2018-11-07.0002\Radial_Accuracy.xlsx');
N=[a(1:1,:) ; b(1:1,:)]
xlswrite('K:\Repeatability_Test\New.xlsx',N);

Comment: Done, updated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case you can have the workbooks open**

You can use the `INDIRECT` function.
In column A, you autofill numbers 1 till 100.
In column B, you put the following formula, which you copy down :
`=INDIRECT("'C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\[2018_11_26.0"&TEXT(A1,"000")&"\Excel.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1")` .

I used `Sheet1` as the name of the worksheet, but this you have to change with the actual name. And I assumed that with cell(1,1) you meant cell `A1`.

As a next step, I would select column B, and copy/paste-as-values the results in column C, to get rid of the 100 references to other excel files, which will slow down opening or re-calculating the workbook every time.

Two sources for the solution : https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-workbook-reference and https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html if you want to do some further reading or fine-tune/trouble-shoot the formula.

But, as mentioned above, the `INDIRECT` function does only work if the other workbook is open. If you close the source workbooks, and you do a `F9` in the workbook with all the results (or re-open again), you will get the `#REF!` again, so therefore my recommendation to copy/paste-as-values once you have the results.
See also here : [Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect)

**Workaround for closed workbooks**

The solution basically creates the direct cell references to the other workbooks as a text string, which you then copy/paste-as-values, and then you either click in each cell, so the formula gets "activated" and will get your result from the other workbook, or you use the text-to-columns functionality of Excel and do this automatically.

Some details. Again assuming that you have numbers 1 till 100 in Column A. Put this in `B1` : `="='C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\[2018_11_26.0"&TEXT(A1,"000")&"\Excel.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"` and copy down.

Now you have to select this range (or the entire column B), and then paste-as-values in column C. If you now click in cell `C1` and tap Enter, you will see that the formula gets executed and you see the actual result (i.e. the value in the other workbook). If you have many cells, this is quite cumbersome, so just select Column C, go to `Data > [Data Tools] Text To Columns`, click `Finish`, and all values from the different workbooks will appear.

Comment: Hello @peter,
Thank you for the reply.

I understand your code, but it is not showing me any value in my file. Just showing #REF!. I cheacked everything, but didnt get how to correct it. 

btw I'm thankful for this help.

kind regards,
Ketan

Comment: @KetanSahu The files need to be open, but I am updating my answer with an alternative (workaround) solution.

Comment: @KetanSahu Did the workaround solution work for you ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and then I have to give up wit this work. But, I'm very grateful for your efforts and suggestions. Thank you :D

Comment: @KetanSahu Sorry to hear that. Let me know if you want to give more details on why/how it did not work for you, so maybe I can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for being so nice, I will surely let you know. At least at this stage I just copied my 70 values directly from my data. but, of course, in future I really don't want to do this manual work. I have to find out something. However, I will see If i'm able to do this thing on Matlab. I hope things will go in the right direction.

Thanks once again. Appreciate you. :D

Comment: @KetanSahu Yeah, manually copying is a pain. Try the workaround method as described above. It worked really fine with my test files (I was actually surprised that it was so easy). And about Matlab, I worked with that under DOS in 1995 for a thesis ... a very long time ago, and I never touched it again since then  ;)    Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub NonRecursiveMethod()

    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim counter As Long

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder("C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\")

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    counter = 1

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1

        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder
        Next oSubfolder

        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=oFile
            sht.Cells(counter, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value
            counter = counter + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        Next oFile
    Loop

End Sub
```