# Regarding the work around for INDIRECT Function

Tags: excel-formula

[How to reference files, each in a different folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477628/how-to-reference-files-each-in-a-different-folder/53477902#53477902)
How to reference files, each in a different folder?

Under 'Workaround for closed workbooks' Peter K. wrote:

> Put this in B1 :
> ="='C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1[2018_11_26.0"&TEXT(A1,"000")&"\Excel.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"
> and copy down.
>
> Now you have to select this range (or the entire column B), and then
> paste-as-values in column C. If you now click in cell C1 and tap
> Enter, you will see that the formula gets executed and you see the
> actual result (i.e. the value in the other workbook).

When I "paste-as-values" `="='C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\[2018_11_26.0"&TEXT(A1,"000")&"\Excel.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"` the result is `="='C:\DATA_DIR\TEST_1\[2018_11_26.0"&TEXT(A1,"000")&"\Excel.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1"`, which is the same.  Causing "now click in cell C1 and tap Enter" to result in formula not being executed.  If I remove = " and the last ", then the formula gets executed.