# Excel INDIRECT function - dynamic link not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I'm using excel 2016 and I've created an INDIRECT formula to combine different cell values into a link but I'm getting #REF!

The cell I'm trying to link to is in another workbook on a network drive and I'm using the UNC folder name. I've compared it to a normal link to the same cell and evaluated my formula and they look identical.

The non-dynamic link (which works!), is this....

```
='\\admin\user group\aob\[excel file.xlsx]Summary'!A1
```

The dynamic link (which doens't work) looks like this....

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$B$8&$B$12&"'!"&Cell_ref!A1)
```

where $B$8 (the file) is: \admin\user group\aob[excel file.xlsx]
and $B$12 is: Summary
and Cell_ref!A1 is: $A$1

The value returned is #REF! but it should be the value from the cell being referenced.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: If the reference is invalid, or if the workbook referenced is not open, `INDIRECT()` will throw a #REF error

Comment: @JvdV - I didn't realise the referenced workbook has to be **open**? That sounds like a major limitation of the INDIRECT function (it obviously doesn't need ot be open in a non-dynamic link).Any idea what techniques people use to work around this?

Comment: If you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish, perhaps we can give suggestions?

Comment: Yes, have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect)

Comment: Thanks
@jkpieterse - I'm creating whole worksheets which link to worksheets in another 'source' workbook (and then adding below the linked area). I was hoping to have a dynamic link for the filename so if a later version of the source file is created (with a different name), it would be easy to update all the links. I suppose I could just use 'Find/Replace' but I was hoping INDIRECT would give a sleeker solution....

Comment: Thanks for your help @JvdV

Comment: Data, Edit links, Change Source is the simplest way I'd say.