# How do I add a variable to an external reference to a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I am looking to link a cell with a cell from a different workbook, but I'm not sure how to edit the reference.

```
='\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm]May'!$G9
```

I am trying to change the "May" value to the previous month.
In a different cell I have the current previous month calculated in cell A1 with

```
=TEXT(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),"mmmm")
```

But when I try to add it, an excel window opens up asking me to update values.

```
='\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm] & $A$1 & '!$G9
="'\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm]" & $A$1 & "'!$G9"
```

Both attempts were unsuccessful.

Using the Indirect method produces A `#REF!` error:

```
 =Indirect("'\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm]" & $A$1 & "'!$G9")
 =Indirect("'\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm]June'!$G9")
```

Comment: Try `="'\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm]" & TEXT($A$1,"mmmm") & "'!$G9"`, or perhaps you need `INDIRECT()`: `=INDIRECT("'\\SERVER\Office\Tools\Excel Files\[Log.xlsm]" & $A$1 & "'!$G9)`?

Comment: The first one only produces a text value and the indirect method cause a reference error when I used the variable and when I hard coded the word June.

Comment: A link to a closed file does not work with `INDIRECT` and will return an error. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect) older thread!

Comment: Looks like I will have to go at it with VBA since I need multiple formulas not just one, thanks!