# Can INDIRECT or an alternative be used in an array formula to reference a closed external workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to populate my sheet with the sum of sales values from an external workbook.

My sheet has monthly dated column headings

The external workbook has sheets named as months "Aug", "Sep" etc.

I am looking for formula that adapts the reference to the external workbook's sheets based on the month value of the column header in my sheet.

However, both routes I have attempted below to calculate this return #REF errors if the external workbook is not open. Is it possible to dynamically reference the external workbook whilst it is closed?

I have attempted to achieved this in two ways:

Where U1 is 01/08/2019

Attempt 1:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'T:\Analytics\KPIs\KPI Data\2019\NewPipeline.xlsx'!"&TEXT(U1,"mmm")&"[Price Per Unit]"))*(INDIRECT("'T:\Analytics\KPIs\KPI Data\2019\NewPipeline.xlsx'!"&TEXT(U1,"mmm")&"[Est. Close Date (Opportunity) (Opportunity)]")>=DATE(YEAR(U1),MONTH(U1),DAY(U1)))*1))
```

Attempt 2:

```
=SUM(IF((INDIRECT("'T:\Analytics\KPIs\KPI Data\2019\NewPipeline.xlsx'!"&TEXT(U1,"mmm")&"[Est. Close Date (Opportunity) (Opportunity)]"))>=DATE(YEAR(U1),MONTH(U1),DAY(U1)),INDIRECT("'T:\Analytics\KPIs\KPI Data\2019\NewPipeline.xlsx'!"&TEXT(U1,"mmm")&"[Price Per Unit]")*1,0))
```

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect/28463798) link helpfull in getting an answer :)

Comment: INDIRECT does not work with closed workbooks.  On the flip side you could use some VBA to monitor the reference cell that holds the month.  When that cell changes, VBA could update/replace referencing formulas potentially, or conversely open the new months workbook in the background.