# How to update the data of many excel files by opening only the file that is used as a source?

Tags: excel

I have a master excel file where data is loaded from an external source. Then there are 10 excel files that take data only from the master file (data source).

How can I update all these 10 files automatically so that I do not go into each of them, but only into the master?

Thank you

Comment: In formulas to those 10 files you have to refer that master file.

Comment: Read these posts [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect), [Link2](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function) But these are really crazy things.