# How to use INDIRECT with logical operators (specifically in a Match function)?

Tags: excel

so here is my function:

`=MATCH(1,--(INDIRECT("'C:\Folder\[Holdings-"& I2 &".xlsx]Holdings - FTH & GAAP_crosstab'!W:W")=""),0)-1`

I2 cell is supposed to be a date, i.e. 20191231

It results in a #REF error, yet when I put in just
`=MATCH(1,--('C:\Folder\[Holdings-20191231.xlsx]Holdings - FTH & GAAP_crosstab'!W:W=""),0)-1` it gives me what I need.

The function is supposed to calculate the number of nonempty cells until the first empty cell in a column, I'm making it this way because I want it to be dynamic, as cell I2 is supposed to be a date input cell.

Is there any way to work around this issue with INDIRECT or is there an alternative way I can do this?

Comment: `TEXT(I2,"yyyymmdd")`. Though I think the file has to be open for INDIRECT to work.

Comment: @BigBen my bad, I mistyped it. Cell I2 is already a TEXT function that references the actual date input cell. Sorry!

Comment: Then no [you can't use INDIRECT if the file is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect)

Comment: @BigBen Is there another function I could use instead of indirect?

Comment: See the link in my previous comment (you may need to refresh the page)

Comment: Calculate the number of cells on the other sheet, then just call that result from the first sheet.