# How to calculate formulas after pasting them as values in Excel without entering in Edit Mode?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with a lot of formulas that are not calculated (COLUMN 2). These formulas are the result of me pasting the formulas of another column (COLUMN 1) as value.

I need to calculate them without going through Edit Mode (either by F2 or by double-clicking with the left mouse button).

This is the before:

```
COLUMN 0                     | COLUMN 1                          | COLUMN 2 (pasted as values)
D:\Documents\2021\[log.xlsx] | ="=INDEX('"&A2&"Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)" | =INDEX('D:\Documents\2021\[log.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)
D:\Documents\2020\[log.xlsx] | ="=INDEX('"&A3&"Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)" | =INDEX('D:\Documents\2020\[log.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)
```

This is the after:

```
COLUMN 0                     | COLUMN 1                          | COLUMN 2 (after double clicking)
D:\Documents\2021\[log.xlsx] | ="=INDEX('"&A2&"Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)" | THIS YEAR
D:\Documents\2020\[log.xlsx] | ="=INDEX('"&A3&"Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)" | LAST YEAR
```

**tl;dr: I want to achieve the above without double clicking every entry in COLUMN 2. Is it doable?**

---

I tried AutoCorrect Options but it failed in this case as it would cover the rest of the rows of the column in with a singular formula, which is no good because every row in this column has a different formula. with AutoCorrect I ended up with

```
COLUMN 0                     | COLUMN 1                          | COLUMN 2 (BAD)
D:\Documents\2021\[log.xlsx] | ="=INDEX('"&A2&"Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)" | THIS YEAR
D:\Documents\2020\[log.xlsx] | ="=INDEX('"&A3&"Sheet1'!A:A,1,1)" | THIS YEAR
```

---

As for the context, I was trying to create a sheet of referenced cell for closed Workbook with INDIRECT(). See [Referencing value in a closed Excel workbook using INDIRECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect) . But because INDIRECT() doesn't play well with closed workbook (it always returns REF!), this is my workaround with using Copy and Paste.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

- Select column 2
- Replace `=` with `=` (same value but it will refresh the cell in the range)

[image: replace equal sign]