# How to pull cell value from closed workbook via formula? (Variable link..)

Tags: excel-formula

I need to pull a value from a cell *closed* workbook to another active workbook.
Standard link formula works fine:
`='W:\Materijalno\robno valoviti karton\[Kartonske ploče 2022.xlsb]Zbirna kartica nova'!D1`
But, that "D1" needs to be variable from D1 to D12(months). That means I would enter the month number(1 or 2 or...12) in some cell(eg 'E2') so that link could take that E2 reference and pull data from corresponding D# in source workbook.
Can something like this be done?:

```
='W:\Materijalno\robno valoviti karton\[Kartonske ploče 2022.xlsb]Zbirna kartica nova'!D&E2`
```

..and what is the best solution without VBA. This is example for one cell and one source, I have many of them, so hardcoding links every month is not a solution.

Comment: Look here: using `INDEX` with a closed workbooks path works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48526323/16578424 - In your case you would use 1, 2, ... 12 as the column value of the index function.

Comment: @Ike, This acctually works on local computer. Yesterday  before I posted the question I tryed this solution on my workstation with files on a server and it didn't work; like "formula was not right" kind of error! ?