# Excel indirect - combine file with cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My reference without indirect looks like this (german version)

```
='[Spektren A Auswertung.xlsx]Power Integral'!$M6
```

I want to have the file in cell B2 and C2, ...
So I tried to combine it with indirect

```
=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!")& $M6
```

But that seems to be wrong. How can I realise this?

Comment: Put all inside `INDIRECT()`. Try- `=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!$M6")`

Comment: That works, but then the cell count is not incremented in a table, instead the whole column has the same entry

Comment: Then try `=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!$M" & ROW($A6))`.

Comment: @Harun24hr whether you put `...!$M`  or `...!M` it doesn't make any difference. You would expect that the $ symbol makes the column reference absolute. However, when concatenating strings (with &) they can no longer be relative. They always are absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function parameters should be in this format:

```
=INDIRECT("'[sample data.xlsx]Sheet1'!B2")
```

For your example:

```
=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!M6")
```

#### To make it more dynamic

If you need to reference many values, e.g. M5, M6, M7, ...
then it's probably worth noting that the address of the cell itself can be constructed using a function, making it more dynamic.

e.g. `ADDRESS(6;13;4)`  results in `M6`, (i.e. the value `4` makes sure there are no absolute references (`$` signs) in the address.

Putting all that together, you could

```
=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!" & ADRESSE(6;13;4))
```

*Note: I'm not sure if `ADRESSE` is correct for your language of excel. It's a calculated guess.*

Using this format you could

```
=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!" & ADRESSE(A1;13;4))
=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!" & ADRESSE(A2;13;4))
=INDIREKT("'[" & B2 & "]Power Integral'!" & ADRESSE(A3;13;4))
```

with values 6,7,8 in the cells A1,A2,A3.

Comment: This solves the problem, but the M6 must not be a string. It is inside a table where column formulars are evaluated and the reference column (here 6) must be incremented.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I don't think there's a way to use the absolute references "$M6" directly, but if you want something more dynamic, you could use the ADDRESS function.

Comment: The comment from above notes the ROW function which works for me. Your could add it to the answer.

Comment: I closed my files and found out that all references are invalid. Even with a full path they only remain valid if the file is open. So I have to remove all Indirect calls.

Comment: May want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect Apparently there is also an `INDEX`  function.