# Use a Cell Reference in INDEX Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet (*Key Numbers*) that references another linked spreadsheet (*[Credit Cards 2023]KeyNum*).

Instead of changing the year in the name every year I want to use a cell reference so that it automatically calculates. I've gotten as far as the below using INDEX - however when I try to use a reference (*$A$2*) in the formula it just returns *#VALUE!*. Here's my attempted formula: `=INDEX("'F:\DeptFolders\Accounting\%Accounting read\%Accounting Staff\Credit Cards\[Credit Cards "&$A$2&".xlsx]KeyNum'!$C$2:$M$14",MONTH($A$1)+1,3)`.

I do not want to use `INDIRECT` as I need this to work without the other spreadsheet being open. Other questions that are marking this as duplicate use INDIRECT which I do not want to do.

**Key Numbers Worksheet:**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Jan |  |
| **2** | 2023 |  |
| **3** | Visa | =INDEX('F:\DeptFolders\Accounting%Accounting read%Accounting Staff\Credit Cards[Credit Cards 2023.xlsx]KeyNum'!$C$2:$M$14,MONTH($A$1)+1,3) |
| **4** | MasterCard | =INDEX('F:\DeptFolders\Accounting%Accounting read%Accounting Staff\Credit Cards[Credit Cards 2023.xlsx]KeyNum'!$C$2:$M$14,MONTH($A$1)+1,4) |

**[Credit Cards 2023]KeyNum Worksheet:**

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **2** |  |  | Mo | Month | Visa | MasterCard |
| **3** |  |  | 1 | January | 123 | 500 |

With the current formulas (the ones listed in the tables) it is correctly returning 123 and 500 in B3 & B4 respectively. However as mentioned I don't want to hardcode `2023` into the INDEX reference.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not doable with `INDEX`.

Comment: @BigBen is there any alternative that works without the other spreadsheet being open? It feels very weird that INDEX can't accept a cell reference.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463798)?