# How do I dynamically change a value in a file path text in excel?

Tags: excel, path, filenames

I have a column (A) with order numbers and a second column (B) which points to the directory from which I need value for that work order number. Column A is manual entry and in Column B the formula is
='\abc\def\jkl\nop\Order#1.xlsm'!sheet1x

What I want to do is when I enter Order #2 in column A the next row the formula in column B should automatically change to ='\abc\def\jkl\nop\Order#2.xlsm'!sheet1x

How do I do that?

I tried concatenating as a string but that doesn't work as it doesn't recognize it as a filepath then

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461672/referencing-value-in-a-closed-excel-workbook-using-indirect

Comment: @BigBen The question tagged doesn't address the specific issue I have. I want some text between single quotes (Order#) to be dynamic

Comment: Yes it does... "The Sheet name is stored as a variable". There's a variable/dynamic component to the filepath. The "normal" approach is to use INDIRECT, except INDIRECT doesn't work with closed workbooks. Your question can be restated as "how do I dynamically reference a cell in a closed workbook," which is exactly  what the linked thread deals with.

Comment: Yes the sheet name is dynamic but I never mentioned I want the sheet name to be dynamic. =INDIRECT("[myExcelFile.xlsm]" & C13 & "!$A$1")    I wanted the myExcelFile name to be dynamic

Comment: What matters is that there is a dynamic element. Whether it's the sheet name or something else is irrelevant. I'm trying to save you time by explaining that `INDIRECT` won't work, and you might consider some of the workarounds in the linked thread.

Comment: I clearly mentioned an example of what I want dynamic and in this case its not enough to have any element dynamic. Sheet name is outside single quotes and your suggestion works there but not for workbook name

Comment: Sorry if I sound rude but I am just saying that the question suggested by you has a different ask and approach

Comment: Getting data from a dynamically changing filepath is exactly what your question and the linked thread (and other questions here) deal with. It is not a straightfoward task and it's probably not worth your time to try to do it with a formula.

Comment: It is very doable to write that formula with VBA btw, as another option.